# Selecting elements of a list based on specific elements of their sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list

```
l = {{123, "style", "", "url", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE"},
     {456, "style", "", "url", "TRUE", "True", "TRUE"},
     {789, "style", "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"},
     {112, "style", "", "url", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE"},
     {223, "style", "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"}};
```

How can I select the ones that their 5th element is `"FALSE"` namely the output should look like:

```
{{789, "style", "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"},
 {223, "style", "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of different ways. The most common ones would be:

```
Cases[l, {_, _, _, _, "FALSE", _, _}]
```

> `{{789, "style", "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"}, {223, "style",   "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"}}`

```
Select[l, #[[5]] == "FALSE" &]
```

> `{{789, "style", "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"}, {223, "style",   "", "url", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
l//Pick[#, #[[All,5]], "FALSE"]&
```

> {{789, style, , url, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE}, {223, style, , url, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE}}